equivalent definition of $\liminf$
I have to prove the equivalence between these $2$ definitions:
$\liminf_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \forall x_n\rightarrow x_0 $
(  where $\liminf_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \inf_{x\in B_r(x_0)-x_0}f(x)$
and $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n)=\sup_{k\in \mathbb{N} }\inf_{n\geq k}
f(x_n)$)
I have first proved $\leq$
now I have to prove the other direction and I did in this way
by definition of $\inf$ I can always find $x_n\in B(x,\frac{1}{n}) : f(x_n)\leq \inf_{y \in B(x,1/n)}f(y)+1/n$  so $\inf_{n>N}f(x_n)\leq \inf_{y\in B(x,1/n)}f(y)+1/n$ so passing to sup I have $\sup_N\inf_{n>N}f(x_n)\leq\sup_n \inf_{y\in B(x,1/n)}= sup_{r>0}\inf_{y\in B(x,r)}$ because I have set $r=1/n$
Is it correct ?How can I improve ?
